# select the first occurance of 3rd column for each of 1st column

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My DB is SQL Server 2008 I have a table that is 3 columns. name ,type , time.

I need to select the first (by time - column 3) event that occurred for each of the names   and is of type 1.
    For example it could be

(George , 1 , 15:00   ) 
                     (George , 3 , 15:00   )
                     (George , 1 , 16:00   )
                     (George , 1 , 16:10   )
                     (Mary , 1 , 15:00   ) 
                     (Mary , 3 , 15:00   )
                     (Mary , 1 , 16:00   )
                     (Mary , 1 , 16:10   )

I need to get only (George , 1 , 15:00   ) 
                   (Mary , 1 , 15:00   )

I did this but it does not work. I know that this is not the right use of distinct.

```
  select distinct(an1. name ), an2.Time 
  from mytable an1
  left join mytable an2
  on an1.id=an2.id
  where an1.type =1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT name, [Time]
FROM (
  SELECT name, [Time], 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name 
                            ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE type = 1) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use cross apply or rownumber or group by

```
  ; with cte
      as
       (
       select distinct name from mytable where type=1
       )
        select * from cte t1
        cross apply
        (
        select top 1 time from mytable t2 where t1.name=t2.name order by time desc) b
```

or

```
with cte
as
(select name,time,
row_number() over (partition by name order by time desc) as rn
from mytable where type=1
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried the first as I could understand it easier. However, it returned one column with the different names and one column with the times that where all the same. I need the first time for each name. Please see my edited post.